# R dplyr: mutate specific values with a reference value found in the same column

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I mutate specific values in a column with a reference value found in the same column? The data frame looks like this:

```
A  Ref  20
A  S1   12
A  S2   76
A  S3   12
A  S4   12
A  XY   89
B  Ref  02
B  S1   12
B  S2   42
B  S3   21
B  S4   12
B  XY   56
```

I would like to mutate by having all S values divided by the Ref value, however not the values for XY.

Basically S1/Ref, S2/Ref, ... S4/Ref for A and B excluding values for XY.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this with `dplyr`.  After grouping by first column, say 'v1', dvide the 'v3' divided by 'v3' where 'v2' is 'Ref' (assuming that there is only one 'Ref' per each unique 'v1' and then replace the 'newcol' where the 'v2' column have values that are not "S\d+"i.e. "S" followed by numbers with 'v3' values.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(v1) %>% 
  mutate(newcol = v3/v3[v2 == "Ref"], 
         newcol = ifelse(!grepl("^S\\d+", v2), v3, newcol))
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   v1 [2]
#      v1    v2    v3 newcol
#   <chr> <chr> <int>  <dbl>
# 1     A   Ref    20   20.0
# 2     A    S1    12    0.6
# 3     A    S2    76    3.8
# 4     A    S3    12    0.6
# 5     A    S4    12    0.6
# 6     A    XY    89   89.0
# 7     B   Ref     2    2.0
# 8     B    S1    12    6.0
# 9     B    S2    42   21.0
#10     B    S3    21   10.5
#11     B    S4    12    6.0
#12     B    XY    56   56.0
```

Suppose, if we need to only replace the 'XY' values with the 'v3', replace the last line with `newcol = ifelse(v2 == "XY", v3, newcol))`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B"), v2 = c("Ref", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "XY", 
"Ref", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "XY"), v3 = c(20L, 12L, 76L, 12L, 
12L, 89L, 2L, 12L, 42L, 21L, 12L, 56L)), .Names = c("v1", "v2", 
"v3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```